# Edit and save a document using Flask and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

```
@app.route('/edit_book/<id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit_book_id(id):
   books = connexion.db.books
   item = books.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(id)})

   if request.method == 'GET':
     if session['username'] is not None:
       return render_template('edit_book.html', username=session['username'], mybooks=item)

   books.update_one({"id": id},
                 {
                     "$set": {"title": request.form.get('title'),
                              "author": request.form.get('author'),
                              "edition": request.form.get('edition'),
                              "price": request.form.get('price'),
                              "image": request.files.get('image'),
                              "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                              }
                 })

return 'Updated, success'
```

The html file:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <h2>Title</h2>
      <input type="text" name="title" size="60" value="{{mybooks.title}}"><br>
    <h2>Author</h2>
      <input type="text" name="author" size="60" value="{{mybooks.author}}"><br>
    <h2>Edition</h2>
      <input type="text" name="edition" size="60" value="{{mybooks.edition}}"><br>
    <h2>Price</h2>
      <input type="text" name="price" size="60" value="{{mybooks.price}}"><br>
    <h2>Upload </h2>
      <input type="file" name="image"/><br>
    <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I use a form to edit a document from the Mongodb database. I can edit the document with the GET method but the problem is with the POST method, I can't update the document. I'm new in Flask.
I think I can't get the fields back after editing.

Comment: Is there any error messages after you POST?

Comment: @dvnguyen No error, but no change in Mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
books.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)},
                  { "$set": {
                             "title": request.form.get('title'),
                              "author": request.form.get('author'),
                              "edition": request.form.get('edition'),
                              "price": request.form.get('price'),
                              "image": request.files.get('image'),
                              "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                             }
                 })
```

Forgot `ObjectId(id)`